# How to get 404 page on rails app without setting "config.consider_all_requests_local = false"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed a solution to a similar issue. There it was told to set 
in **application_controller**

```
def not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

And I had to set

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

In **production.rb** file. Then when I entered a wrong url it started giving 404 page. But one disadvantage of setting it to `false` is I wont be able to see the rails error on the browser when something goes wrong. How can I achieve this `404` exception without setting it to `false` ?

Comment: The idea of running your app in production mode is to prevent your errors from showing up to the user. You can still check your errors in 'log/production.log'.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `consider_all_requests_local` to `false`, when `true`, it's for development mode.

As to the exception, you might use https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification to send the exception information to your email or slack or other..